# Map getter isn't defined for Map<String, String>

Tags: dictionary, dart

I am new on Dart, I want to map a list of objects to only get the attribute `firstName`, but I am getting that error:

```
Error: The getter 'firstName' isn't defined for the class 'Map<String, String>'.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
```

```
void main() {
  var employes = [
  {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
  {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
  {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
];
  var mapFirstName = employes.map((detail) { return {"firstName": detail.firstName}});
    
  print(mapFirstName);
}
```

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 3):

In Dart, you have to use bracket notation instead of the dot notation to access the values of the keys in the map.

Your code should look like:

```dart
var mapFirstName = employes.map((detail) => {"firstName": detail["firstName"]});
```